# How do you configure Java SSL client socket to behave like Python?

Tags: python, java, ssl, tls1.2

I am attempting to wrap application TCP data with SSL to transmit data to a server with TLS 1.2.

I can achieve this using Python, but want to implement in Java. I have, what I believe to be, functionally the same process written in both languages, but obviously something is fundamentally different here.

I have the proper certificates installed on Windows in the certificate registry.

I can functionally send a message to the server using Python with the following code:

```
import socket
import ssl

HOST, PORT = 'server.com', 8000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#sock.settimeout(10)

wrappedSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)#, ciphers="ADH-AES256-SHA")

# CONNECT AND PRINT REPLY
wrappedSocket.connect((HOST, PORT))

wrappedSocket.send(b"Hello")

wrappedSocket.close()
```

However, in Java, I can complete the handshake, but no messages are actually transmitted.

This is the Java

```
...

String[] protocols = new String[]{"TLSv1.2"};
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket("server.com", 8000);
socket.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
socket.addHandshakeCompletedListener(new HandShakeListener(socket));
socket.startHandshake();

...

class HandShakeListener implements HandshakeCompletedListener{
             
     SSLSocket socket;
             
     public HandShakeListener(SSLSocket socket) {
          this.socket = socket;
                
     }

     @Override
     public void handshakeCompleted(HandshakeCompletedEvent arg0) {
          System.out.println("Handshake Completed");

          PrintWriter out;
      try {
           out = new PrintWriter(
                      new BufferedWriter(
                       new OutputStreamWriter(
                        socket.getOutputStream())));
      } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return;
      }
          
          out.println("Hello from Java");
      System.out.println("Sending message");
      out.println();
      out.flush();
          out.close();
     }
```

I am using the JVM arguments  `-Djavax.net.debug=all -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT`

And the Djavax.net debug message shows that the handshake is successful and data is writing.

My understanding is that Python and Java in this circumstance are functionally the same, however I am successfully receiving messages on the server when I send from Python, but no messages make it through using Java.

What am I missing/what is the difference between these?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

As requested, I have moved away from using the event listener, however I am now only able to send data to the server when the socket closes.

```
            // Create an SSLContext
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, null, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            // Connect to the server
            SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket("server.com", 8000); // Replace with your target server and port
            sslSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(sslSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            sslSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);

            // Perform SSL handshake
            sslSocket.startHandshake();

            // Send data to server
            OutputStream outputStream = sslSocket.getOutputStream();
            String message = "This is a test message";
            outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();

            // Send more data to server
            String additionalMessage = "This is an additional message";
            outputStream.write(additionalMessage.getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();

            // Close the SSL socket when done
            sslSocket.close();
```

On the server side, the message is revieved as one string, as though the "flush()" method isn't flushing the buffer.

Comment: You've buggered up the Java implementation by trying to send data when the handshake is being completed I guess. Try writing data after calling the `startHandshake` method call. By the way, the `event` received through the `HandShakeCompleted` call already contains a getter to get tot the socket. Please study the interfaces you are trying to extend before doing so; I even intuitively knew that the code was bad on that aspect before looking it up.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment. 
I could have been more to the point in the original post without using the event listener, but my original attempt was to do what you have suggested, and concerns about asynchronous processes led to the code I posted, however that is not solving the problem. I did what you suggested, and it is yielding the same results.

Comment: Could you post an update of your code under the current code in the question? As it stands, I think that trying to send data at any part of the handshake handling is fundamentally wrong. Obviously, something else can trigger issues, but I think resolving the handshake issue would at least eliminate that part of the problem. To quote the doc of `startHandshake`: "This method is synchronous for the initial handshake on a connection *and returns when the negotiated handshake is complete.* " As it is synchronous, it doesn't make sense to use the callback for that.

Comment: Right, "RTFM", as they say...

Comment: `outputStream.write(message.getBytes())``: you probably need to add a newline here. None of the above commentary is correct. You *can't* write before the handshake is complete. If you try, you will block until then.

Comment: We currently don't know anything about the protocol or the server implementation. How do you know that the data is expected and retrieved at the server? How did you determine that it was only received when the socket is closed? @user207421 What the hell do you mean with "None of the above commentary is correct"? I actually looked up if you were a newbe user because of that broad, unclarified comment.

Answer (score 0):

As documented, [OutputStream.flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush()) does nothing. You might wrap it with a [BufferedOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html#BufferedOutputStream(java.io.OutputStream)) to percolate your request.

This becomes :

```
OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream(), 1024);
String message = "This is a test message";
outputStream.write(message.getBytes());
outputStream.flush();

// Send more data to server
String additionalMessage = "This is an additional message";
outputStream.write(additionalMessage.getBytes());
outputStream.flush();
```